# Maven get conflicted jars to exclude

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have following problem:

I have 6-7 and more paths where from my jar is passing to classpath, and I need to get all nasted jars in my pom, and set exclusions. For now I use my Intellij Idea to build dependency tree, then use search and find all jars, and proceed exclusion one by one. Its very slow process, because Intellij works VERY slow with dependency tree. Can you suggest me some better way to do all exclusions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still a manual step, but it gets round the problem of a slow IDE.

On the command line, run

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

This will print out the nested jars. I would then exclude them manually in the pom.

Comment: Thanks, this approach much better

Answer (score 1):

You can ask IntelliJ to generate you maven  dependency diagram (ctrl + alt + shift + U).

From that diagram you can right-click any dependency and exclude it. Relevant section in pom.xml will be automatically updated (`<exclusion>` elements added).

Comment: Actually I'm using this way to do exclude, and it's extremely slow

Comment: you can switch off "auto import changes" setting in maven plugin configuration. This way it will allow you to exclude everything at once, without reloading things (assuming reloading makes things slower)